# Can I make requests from an extension without requesting <all_urls> permission?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am generally wary of extensions that request the `<all_urls>` permission.

I've had to reluctantly use it in [my own extension](https://github.com/kodus/server-log) as I couldn't find any other way to do a simple web-request without being hit by CORS restrictions.

I don't understand why these restrictions apply to extensions?

Presumably there's a good reason.

But I don't need to snoop on requests in transit - this extension is a devtools-extension, and in terms of observing requests, it gets what it needs from `chrome.devtools.network` API and doesn't need the `<all_urls>` permission for that.

I had to enable `<all_urls>` solely so I could make an outgoing request [here](https://github.com/kodus/server-log/blob/master/src/panel.ts#L79-L95).

Is there a different way to avoid the CORS restrictions for a simple outgoing web-request?

A less "drastic" permission that doesn't seem as scary to end users?

Comment: If you make the request to the current tab after a user gesture, all you need is the [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission. Otherwise you can try using the [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions). P.S. A "simple web-request" can do a lot of damage by exposing the user's data or by fetching and running malicious remote code so no wonder extensions can't do it without a permission.

Comment: @wOxxOm `activeTab` doesn't work for me... "after a user gesture", I think that's the problem? This extension needs to make a request when it sees a certain header - I'm betting things like async requests do not constitute a user gesture? Anyhow, with `activeTab`, my outgoing requests get blocked.